# white list ip addresses

Tags: c#, httpcontext

i have the following function that checks a list of ip address if the ip address is not found in the list it will throw an error as follows

```
public Task TestIp<T>(dynamic body)
        {
            var httpContext = DependencyResolver.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()?.HttpContext;


            if (!_ips.Contains(httpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress)) //passes ::1
            throw new Exception("invalid");
}
```

one of my ips in list example is 127.0.0.1 which is a local host. but with the above code i get the following ip address passed as ::1

so this is what i tried

```
var remoteIp = httpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
            remoteIp = remoteIp.MapToIPv4()

            if (!_ips.Contains(remoteIp))
            throw new Exception("invalid");
```

but now the remoteIp = 0.0.0.1
so now the remoteIp doesnt match the ip adress stored `127.0.0.1 !=  0.0.0.1`

Comment: IPv6 and IPv4 address are not necessarily equivalent and you will need to whitelist both

Comment: but if i pass a different ip address thats not a local host how would i know whats the equivalent to it

Comment: Not all PCs are configured the same.  Some have localhost as the loopback IP 127.0.0.1 and others do not.  I think 0.0.0.1 is IPAny.  So maybe test for either Loopback or IPANY.

Comment: @josh If you look at the docs for MapToIPv4() it says in the remarks that you can "Call IsIPv4MappedToIPv6, which will return true if the IP address is originally IPv4 written as IPv6, or false otherwise." If it was not an IPv4 address converted to IPv6, then there is no direct equivalent. They are two entirely different addressing methods https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.maptoipv4?view=netcore-3.1